# Attempting to create a simple R-Shiny GUI - Receiving Errors when trying to input items.

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a simple R-shiny page, using this as my ui file

```
library(shiny) 

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel('Biomarker Comparison'),

        plotOutput('plot'),

fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         h4('Options'),
         selectInput('var', label='Choose an ADLB_TDU Assay', 
                    choices = c('BASOPHILS', 'CD3', 'CD4', 'CD8', 'CD19', 'EOSINOPHILS', 'IMMUNOGLOBULIN E', 'Leukocyte', 'Lymphocyte', 'Monocyte', 'Neutrophil'))
         )
)


        ))
```

My server file looks like this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
TDU = read.csv('data/adlb_tdu.csv')
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==180.0),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==20.0),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==90.1),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==90.2),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==110.1),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==110.2),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==110.3),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==110.4),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==130.1),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==130.2),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==150.1),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==170.1),]
TDU = TDU[!(TDU$VISITNUM==180.1),]
TDU$RACECOL = NULL
TDU$LBENDTC = NULL
TDU$LBENDT = NULL
TDU$LBENDX = NULL
TDU$LBENTM = NULL
TDU$LBENTX = NULL
TDU$LBPBLFL = NULL 
TDU$LBDRVFL = NULL
TDU$LBENTPT = NULL
TDU$LBENTPTN = NULL

shinyServer(

  function(input, output) {

    output$plot = renderPlot({

      dataset = subset(TDU, LBTEST==str(input$var), select = STUDYID:LBTPT, drop=FALSE)

      ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x= VISITNUM, y = LBBLCHGR, col=factor(ARMAN))) + 
        geom_line(data = dataset, aes(x=VISITNUM,y=LBBLCHGR,group=SUBJID)) +
        geom_point(size=3) + 
        facet_wrap( ~ ARMAN, ncol=2, scales="free_x") +
        ylab("Relative Change in Percent") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust=2)) +
        scale_color_discrete(name="Dosage") +
        xlab("Day") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18))

    })




  }
)
```

But whenever I try to select an option from the select menu, a graph isn't generated, and the result is a series of cryptic messages.

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7282
 chr "BASOPHILS"
Warning in is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Warning in max(panels$ROW) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SCALE_Y", value = 1L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
 chr "CD3"
Warning in is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Warning in max(panels$ROW) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SCALE_Y", value = 1L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Comment: In the `subset`, shouldn't it be `input$var` instead of  `str(input$var)`? Try printing the head of the `dataset`. And you should probably do something to deal if `NULL` inputs.

Comment: Thanks!  The problem was that the str() function was messing up the dataframe.